# IndexError: list index out of range python json

Tags: python, json

When i excecute this code, for a json file

```
data = []

with open('subscriberaa') as f:
     for line in f:
        data = json.loads(line)

print str(data["services_key"][0]["code_key"])
```

I've this error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is for a null list into a parse string ([])

"services_key" : []

How i can try and catch this error?

Comment: from your terminology, it seems you know what `try-except` blocks are, just put your `print` inside of it and catch `except IndexError`

Comment: I'd go with exception handling but you could also check before continuing `if data["services_key"]:`

Comment: You *do* realize that you are completely overwriting `data` after every line, don't you? After your `with open(...` line, just do `data = json.loads(f.read())` and the entire contents of the file will be loaded into `data`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in python the term is try and except but i know what you mean

here's what you can do

```
data = []

with open('subscriberaa') as f:
     for line in f:
        data = json.loads(line)
try:
   print str(data["services_key"][0]["code_key"])
except:
   //code that runs when error happens
```

hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

you can use time interval ...

```py
import time
data = []

with open('subscriberaa') as f:
     for line in f:
        data = json.loads(line)
        time.sleep(2)

print str(data["services_key"][0]["code_key"])
```